# Query on Thread execution

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have started four threads (multithreading) & assigned a task for each of the threads.
The task for each of the thread is uploading a file to the server

I want to perform the following functionalities.

i>I want to assign the next set of files to the 4 new threads only when all the existing 4 threads has completed its execution.

How can I determine whether all the existing 4 Threads has completed their execution ?

I used the condition

```
for (Thread thread : threads) {

    if(thread.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED || getAlive()) == false){

     ++ counter ;

    }
}
```

to find the status of the threads .

If the counter value becomes 4 , then it means that all the threads are not alive or terminated.

I get a notification for every file which is getting uploaded.

After I found that the counter value = 4 , I again assigned four new files to be uploaded using four new threads.

There can be a situation where a file didn't get uploaded the first time , so I need to reassign it again . I found out that , I am reassigning a file which is already uploaded.
So , its a duplicate upload. I assigned the file again since I received no notification for the upload successfull for that specific file.

Also , it can be that the code mentioned above is not giving the proper status of the threads. It can be that the thread was still performing the operation when I reassigned the file again to be uploaded.

Since I used four threads , counter = 4 means that all the threads have performed their operation.

What should be my approach in solving the issue ?

Comment: use `join()` to block the calling thread until the thread completes.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [CountDownLatch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

Answer (score 0):

is it mandatory to upload files in set of 4

Future can be used to block til operation is complete
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the good one.. waiting for threads to complete

http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2007/05/when-to-join-threads.html